# QGIS crashed when click on anything in plugin manager

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, arch-linux

When I click on anything inside of the plugin manager QGIS crashes immediately. (QGIS 3.0.3, arch linux)

Running from the command line this error shows up on crashing:

> free(): invalid pointer
>
> [1]    29800 abort (core dumped)  qgis

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Please report it to: https://issues.qgis.org/issues

Comment: I reported it. https://issues.qgis.org/issues/18999

Answer (score 1):

Probably this bug is related to QtWebKit. It looks similar to [this one](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=231222)

More detailed log:

```
QNetworkReplyHttpImplPrivate::_q_startOperation was called more than once QUrl("https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml?qgis=3.2")
[New Thread 0x7fff78e8d700 (LWP 16447)]
[Detaching after fork from child process 16448]
[New Thread 0x7fff6b7ff700 (LWP 16449)]
free(): invalid pointer
```

Temporary solution that works in my case (QGIS 3.4.2 + Arch Linux):

1. please check Java versions you have installed
2. leave only java-8-openjdk  and remove others
3. try to run QGIS